# Integral of $|\cos(ax))|\times e^{-x^2/b}$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, absolute-value, gaussian-integral

I can compute the following integral very easily ($a$ and $b$ are real and positive):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(ax)\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi b}}\cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{b}}\,dx = e^{-\frac{a^2b}{4}}$$

Now, I want to compute the following integral in terms of $a$ and $b$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\cos(ax)|\times \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi b}}\cdot e^{-\frac{x^2}{b}}\,dx =\text{ ?}$$

Comment: Consider splitting the integral into intervals on which cosine is positive and negative.

Comment: @AlexR That sure would be a lot of intervals!